# Cisco ASA Multiple Tunnels

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa

Is it possible to have multiple VPN's between an ASA and other peer and each tunnel have it's own PSK?

For example, crypto map 1 would have PSK "test" and look after traffic between 10.10.10.0/24 and 11.11.11.0/24.

Crypty map 2 would have the same peer, PSK "test2" and look after traficc between 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.30.0/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as those tunnels are each to their own peers. PSK's are assigned in the tunnel group, so it'd look something like this:

> tunnel-group [IP ADDRESS OF TUNNEL 1's PEER] type ipsec-l2l
>   tunnel-group [IP ADDRESS OF TUNNEL 1's PEER] ipsec-attributes
>     pre-shared-key test
>
> tunnel-group [IP ADDRESS OF TUNNEL 2's PEER] type ipsec-l2l
>   tunnel-group [IP ADDRESS OF TUNNEL 2's PEER] ipsec-attributes
>     pre-shared-key test2